# Would coating a space ship in liquid nitrogen mask its thermal signature?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, stealth

One of the biggest problems with stealth in space is heat.

My idea was to have a gap between hulls filled with a liquid similar to liquid nitrogen which would chill the outer hull and electric circuits to low temperatures.

Would doing this make a drifting ship disguised as an asteroid harder to detect?

Comment: Generating gasses from your ship might make it more visible than the heat you're covering. People out there will be looking for cold things generating vapor (like comets) as navigational hazards, if nothing else.

Comment: Liquid nitrogen is only cold because at Atmospheric pressure, it will phase change to a gas, requiring latent energy to boil. Once all of the LN2 has boiled away, the N2 can continue to heat up. It would therefore be possible to build a 'heat capacitor' like in Mass Effect using this principle. You can even vary the temperature of the heat capacitor by varying the pressure. However, this would not be very 'space efficient'...

Comment: Yet another "I don't understand the basics of physics" questions.

Comment: You do not ask for alterantive ways to remove heat from your ship but maybe some kind of advanced heat to electricity generator such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator  would allow a plausable way for your to do something to transform the heat into something less detectable.

Comment: I don't think it's going to hide your engines when you launch, and that's what's being watched for.

Comment: Do you know what direction possible observers will be looking from, or can they be anywhere?  E.g. if you're in the asteroid belt, and know that any observer will be at or inside Mars' orbit, then you could perhaps cool the sunward side while radiating excess heat from the other.

Comment: @TafT, A thermoelectric generator does not turn heat in to electricity. In fact, _nothing_ can do that. If it were possible, then your home refrigerator would _make_ electricity from the heat that it removes from your food instead of using electricity. Any system that makes any kind of mechanical or electric energy "from heat" actually is extracting the energy from the _flow_ of heat from a hot "source" to a cooler "sink."

Comment: @TafT Thermodynamics disagree with you on that; you'd need some cold sink, like the vastness of space… but that wouldn't be very sneaky.

Comment: Do you know how cold space actually is? You'd want to be surrounding your ship with massive amounts of decent thermally *insulating* material so that the heat stays *inside* it and your astronauts don't freeze. Liquid nitrogen is a poor insulator in comparison. If the ship were coated in a perfect insulator, its outer skin would be the same temperature as space, regardless its inner temperature, and you wouldn't be able to see it by pointing your heat-seeing camera at the night sky because it's externally the same temperature as everything around it

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think for peltier devices you do need a cold synch but I thought that some small amount of the thermal energy transformed into eletrical energy in the process?  Problem being it is a very small percentage so you cannot sustain a mechnical pump ina fridge for example.  I was expected to add some magic hand waving sci-fi efficentcy ontop.  True if you dumped heat into space as the synch your ship would be only near background level not at background level but that might be enough for some level of concealment?

Comment: Skim reading is not enough.  I feel a trip to Physics exchange at lunchtime coming on.  Always a struggle to wrap my head aboud there the energy is coming from in these situaltions.  At the moment I am at the "total heat in A must end up being less than heat in A+B if some energy has left the system as an electric current" state.  Maybe years since I did physics or materials science.

Comment: (ps; nitrogen is a solid at space temperatures, and chilling electronics to space temperatures typically puts them well outside their operating temperature range)

Comment: @TafT The energy comes from the temperature gradient. I'm not sure whether the average temperature goes _down_ or just doesn't _rise_, but the hot thing must get colder and the cold thing must get warmer.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 a temperature gradient is not a form of energy though, it is a difference in two amounts of energy of a given type.  I think that if you take energy away in the form of electrical energy the average temperature will go down proportional with the electrical energy extracted so that overall the energy in the system is conserved.  If this was not the case and the total termal energy stayed the same, the electrical energy would be "free".  At least that is what I am thinking at the moment.

Comment: @TafT The hot thing cools down more than the cool thing warms up, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle).

Comment: @SolomonSlow I still think the peltier devices and similar do infact extract heat that is flowing through them and covnert some of it into energy.  Most steam driven turnbines and combsion engines also transform heat into other energy (all be it not that efficently in some cases).  The question is could you do something with the other energy that is less detectible like shining a laser out at something you expect no one will be watching to transfer the energy there as an end point.

Comment: @TafT, Yes. Exactly. "Heat that is flowing _through_ them." A Peltier device embedded in the hull of a space ship in the cold depths of space would make electricity in proportion to the amount of the ship's internally generated heat that flows through the device and radiates out into space.  If your goal is to _stop_ heat from radiating out into space, the Peltier device is not going to be any help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your aim is to use liquid nitrogen to mask heat, it will be just a temporary mitigation.

The heat from the ship will cause the liquid nitrogen to heat up and evaporate in the vacuum of space.

If you want to keep the liquid nitrogen in place, you need to cool it down and dump that heat away. But dumping the heat away is what your ship was doing already before you put the liquid nitrogen in place.

Basically this system will attenuate your thermal signature as long as your reservoir of liquid nitrogen lasts.

Comment: space is about 3K, liquid nitrogen is about 77K. Liquid nitrogen _won't_ hide your thermal signature. It may temporarily reduce it, but you'll still be there, visible against the background. Liquid helium is at 4K though so it would work much more like how you describe

Comment: It'll evaporate, not sublime as it's not starting out as a solid

Comment: it can as well sublime - depending on the pressure it is kept at.

Comment: Basically it would be about as effective as freezing the ships hull in a spaceport, or something, right?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner, The difference between the liquid nitrogen trick and "freezing the ship's hull in a spaceport" is that there's a [_phase change_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-change_material) when the nitrogen boils.  The temperature of your entirely-solid hull will start to rise from the very moment that you start to generate heat inside of it. But the temperature of a hull that is cooled by an evaporating liquid will not even _begin_ to rise until all of the liquid has boiled away.\* But like L.Dutch says, the effect is temporary. Eventually, all of the liquid boils away.

Comment: \* I'm assuming that your cooling system keeps the liquid at a constant pressure until it's gone.

Comment: Won't that "gap between hulls" turn the ship into a bomb as the LN warms up?

Comment: @Tristan: Thermal emissions go up with the 4th power of the temperature. That's one of the highest exponents you're likely to see in ordinary physics. Cooling down a ship to 1/4 (300K to 75K) reduces its thermal emissions to 1/256, so 99.6% less. In the asteroid belt, that is effectively invisible.

Comment: @MSalters sure, the power is high, so the reduction in total intensity is large, but because we know we're working with black bodies you can work around it by observing only specific frequencies, at which point we're looking at Planck's law rather than Stefan-Boltzman and the intensiity goes like 1/(e^(1/T) - 1) at a given frequency. For T > hf/k this relationship is essentially linear so if we want to detect anything hotter than 3K, we just need to look at any frequency lower than 62.51 GHz. So any radio telescope, and most microwave ones will detect it

Comment: note, this frequency will enable to you to spot anything hotter than 3 K fairly easily, so would even work for a liquid helium cooled craft. For something cooled with liquid nitrogen at 77 K, anything below something more like 1.6 THz (a reasonably cool infrared) would work. Also, looking at the actual graph, the linear behaviour seems to actually start  at a temperature about 1/4 of the one given here, meaning you can potentially push the frequency a bit higher. Generally you're going to want to be using a frequency nearer this upper limit, because then you'll have a bigger total intensity

Comment: @Tristan couldn't the OP just lower the air pressure inside this "envelope" to lower the ebullition temperatur of liquid nitrogen? BTW, liquid nitrogen is not "cold", it becomes cold when it evaporates. You can have liquid nitrogen at room temperature, as long as you do not allow it to evaporate (inside a sealed container, for example).

Comment: @SJuan76 'BTW, liquid nitrogen is not "cold", it becomes cold when it evaporates.'  That isn't correct unless you think 77 degrees kelvin isn't cold.  It does take more heat to evaporate than to raise it's temperature a few degrees, so the evaporation as a big effect on cooling it's surroundings if that's what you mean.

Comment: @SJuan76 true, lower air pressure will do this, and obviously just exposing it to vacuum would lower the boiling point significantly. Still, if it's fairly easy to spot anything hotter than 3K by just looking at a narrow 62 GHz band, as I showed above, even liquid nitrogen at a cooler temperature won't cut it. You need to actually cool the surface of your ship to match the CMBR, which would require an internal heat reservoir, and can obviously only be used for brief periods of time

Answer (score 32):

Depends where your ship is.

If you're in, say, Earth's orbit, or anywhere inside the Main Belt, anyone who happens to detect the ship with passive sensors might wonder why an asteroid so close to the sun is so cold (its surface ought to approximate black body temperature for its distance from the star) -- and if you're in interstellar space (or near it, like in the Oort Cloud) it'll still shine like a beacon because *liquid nitrogen is too hot*.

Now, the general idea seems sound, until you wonder where you're going to dump waste heat from inside the ship to avoid evaporating the liquid (something-or-other) in the tween-hulls space.  In the end, the ship still has to radiate all the heat that's produced inside to keep from cooking the occupants and/or electronics etc. -- all your chilled outer hull can do is delay the inevitable, and for that, it's really no better than filling that same space with a vacuum (like in a Dewar flask) to limit heat transfer to the outer hull.

Any of these methods require a way to store heat inside the inner hull for some period of time, and can only last as long as that heat storage can be maintained.

The one exception here is if you're trying to hide in a region of space where objects run around 50-100K at the surface; in that case, as suggested in comments, you could use liquid nitrogen mixed with small (or trace) amounts of contaminants like carbon monoxide, ethane, and so forth with similar boiling points (they'll tend to have similar molecular weights, so you at least know which boiling points to look up), and allow it to evaporate to look like a small, prematurely active comet (even to a spectrgraph, if you get the gas mix right).  This would prolong the life of your cloak, more so if you can deeply minimize heat production inside the spaceship.

Comment: If the ship was large enough it could contain a vast inner vacuum area that could be slowly filled with evaporating nitrogen. It should work for a while until the pressure inside reached dangerous levels.

Comment: I'd upvote just for "liquid nitrogen is too hot" (you'd need liquid helium at ~4K, still a degree hotter than the background at 2.7K and likely causing all kinds of issues with the containing materials). But the rest of the answer is correct as well.

Comment: came here to post pretty much exactly this answer, but glad to see it was already here, and the phrase "liquid nitrogen is too hot" is solid gold

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica LN2 is only too hot at Standard Atmospheric Pressure. There is very very little reason to have STP on any space craft.

Comment: @Aron Looks as if it's too hot as a liquid even at zero pressure, see https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/nitrogen-d_1421.html.

Comment: @Aron LN2 doesn't exist at STP -- it can't.  Standard Temperature and Pressure is around 1 atm at either 273K or 293K (depending which STP you're using).  Liquid nitrogen has to be below about 113K at atmospheric, but nitrogen freezes at 63K in vacuum (maybe a couple degrees lower at atmospheric pressure, except there are no other common gases that could pressurize it at that temperature).

Comment: As I read this, it occurs to me maybe heat can be taken care by boiling a liquid, captured in it's latent heat. Perhaps the vapor could also be used as fuel if you are using an ion drive.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde Latent heat of vaporization isn't generally huge unless the liquid is water.  And keeping the vapor is just a way of storing the heat inside the ship -- still has the same limitations.  Further, you wouldn't run an ion drive when you're hiding; the drive plume emits light as the electrons recombine with the ions.

Comment: In interstellar space, you'd still be practically invisible at 77K, unless you're a planet-sized ship. Yes, you're hot, but your surface area is simply too small to emit a noticeable amount of photons. You're barely warmer than the Kuyper Belt Objects (which sit at 50K, and vastly outnumber you)

Comment: @MSalters Given the size of the Kuiper Belt, and the orbits of its objects, it's very likely some are colder than that.  Pluto, for instance, spends several decades per orbit inside the orbit of Neptune, and gets warm enough to evaporate the nitrogen snow off the surface (hence above 63K)  and form a temporary atmosphere.  I'll edit the Kuiper Belt reference in my answer.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: So a ship surrounded by a cloud of freshly evaporated N2 looks quite a bit like a KBO, right?

Comment: @MSalters Or a prematurely activated primordial comet, perhaps.  However, a spectrograph would show the N2 is much too pure (N2 on Pluto's surface is contaminated with carbon monoxide and light hydrocarbons like ethane, just to pick species that evaporate at roughly similar temperatures).  If you intended to his this phenomenon to improve stealth, you could intentionally use a mix of N2 with a few percent CO and C2H6 (and traces of other stuff).

Comment: @ZeissIkon: But you need a lot of photons to reliably detect that. Pluto is big, a spaceship isn't. You're masquerading as a ~1 km snowball with a whiff of nitrogen. You'd run out of liquid nitrogen before someone has accumulated enough readings to reliably detect the missing hydrocarbons. And who is tracking all the KBO's simultaneously?

Comment: @MSalters impure LN2 is probably no harder to get than the pure stuff, especially if you can scoop it off real comets and KBOs.  Why not improve your cloak when you have the option?

Answer (score 24):

Nitrogen isn't inherently cold. It has some properties that make it useful for refrigeration/cryonic applications: it's easily available, not very reactive, and because it stays liquid at very cold temperatures, we can pipe it around or dunk things in it. You can think of it as something that *transports* or *stores* "cold", but it doesn't *make* "cold".

So it doesn't really answer the question of "where does the cold come from?" aka "where are you moving the heat to?"

Spacecraft contain components that generate heat: electronics, engines, people. Unless you want your spacecraft to melt, you have to get rid of that heat somehow, and in the long run you have to get rid of it as fast as you're generating it.

On Earth, the three ways of shedding heat are conduction, convection, and radiation.

In space, conduction isn't a thing (your ship isn't touching any other objects), so you're left with the other two.

- Radiation is the usual method, but that's how you get detected - effectively you're shining red-hot, for some values of "red".
- Convection means carrying around some kind of thermal mass, transferring heat from the rest of your ship into that mass, and then jettisoning the mass. But then even if your ship is cold, the ejecta will be hot and detectable. If you only heat it up a little bit above ship temperatures, it's not going to be weight-efficient - you'll be carrying around a lot of mass and you'll run out quickly. (Nitrogen is not a great choice for this, BTW - you want something with a high [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_specific_heat_capacities) per kilogram.)

In the long run, there is no physics-compatible solution that will stop you from emitting heat, which then makes you detectable. About the only thing you *can* do here is bank that heat for short periods - you might be able to chill your hull while heating up an insulated reservoir hidden inside the ship, which might make you harder to detect for a while, but eventually you'll need to dump that heat one way or another and then you'll be extra-visible. This could be tactically useful if you know exactly when you need concealment, but not for ongoing concealment.

Comment: Yes! Good dissection of the logical error: 'It doesn't *make* "cold".'

Comment: What about radiating the heat away directionally so that, even though you're detectable, it'd be only within a narrow cone (that likely is pointing away from whatever's trying to detect you)?

Comment: This is a great answer both in that it explains the physics, and explaining why thermal masking might be possible for short periods, but not indefinitely. I'm imagining that prolonged use of "thermal stealth" would cause the inside of the ship to get hotter and hotter until the crew begin suffering heat stroke. If you're not venting heat away, then it's gotta be staying in the ship!

Comment: @jamesdlin [Atomic Rockets covers this.](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacewardetect.php#id--Strategic_Combat_Sensors--There_Ain't_No_Stealth_In_Space--Why_Not?_Let_me_count_the_ways--Well_I'll_just_beam_my_heat_the_other_way!) If the cone is too narrow, you need an excessive amount of power just to pipe heat into the radiators properly (and that means turning up your reactors, which make even more heat...), and if it's even decently wide, all your adversary needs is a smattering of drones around the system for one to pick up the signal and relay the detection down the line.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Kinda like old-fashioned submarine warfare, where staying submerged meant running down your batteries and building up CO2.

Answer (score 7):

The real problem is, where is all that heat coming from? You see, if you stop all systems on board, your ship will cool down to the same temperature of any asteroid around - so is, depending exclusively on how much radiation is exposed to - but, of course, that is probably too cold for the critters inside it.

You can, of course, cool down your external hull trying to disguise your heat signature, but not for too long. Your liquid similar to liquid nitrogen will soak up heat very quickly, and thus will stop working. You'll either run out of liquid, or will have to cool it down in a termal cycle, but you can't do that without getting rid of the excess heat somewhere else... thermodynamics is a hard mistress.

But yes, for a short period of time you could reduce your heat signature, for example before making an infiltration attempt on enemy territory. It won't last very long, so you pray to get through quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Geoffrey has it right but let me rephrase it.

Your *actual* problem is to cool down your hull.

Phrased this way it is immediately clear that flooding a whole space between two hull layers is wasteful and unnecessary. For example, a proven way to cool down surfaces (you'll need to get down to 3K or so to match the microwave background) are pipes with coolant, much like in your freezer. Since [nitrogen becomes solid at around 60K](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/nitrogen-d_1421.html) even at zero pressure you'll need something like liquid helium in those pipes. That will bring your temperature down to at least 4K. The technology exists today — it is used to cool superconductors.

Other posts have pointed out that keeping the hull cold is unsustainable because it prevents radiating the heat away which is generated inside by electronics, machines and organisms. The ship will heat up over time; darned entropy. But for a while it can work, principally.

The main goal of such a ship design would be to minimize the amount of heat which reaches the surface from the interior. The reason is two-fold: First of all, less heat is obviously easier to deal with. But secondly, and perhaps most importantly, what we have here is basically an inside-out fridge, where the cold surface faces outside. Like all mechanisms, *the cooling creates additional heat.* That's well-known for laptops: If you can get the heat production down to a level that can be cooled passively you have an additional jump in battery time because the active cooling itself needs energy which is now available for computing. The following strategies can be employed to increase mission time:

- Minimize the heat flux to the outer surface. This will reduce the necessary cooling effort and, as said above, reduce *heat production from cooling.* The heat flux can be tackled from two sides:

  - Minimize the overall energy consumption of the ship. Eventually all energy ends up as heat and must be dealt with. A good design starts at the root of the problem. Minimal life support, no creature comforts.
  - Interrupt the heat flux through insulation. The most effective insulation will be much like a thermos: A multi-layer hull with the layers separated by vacuum, with mirror surfaces.
- Have a dedicated heat sink inside the ship which in turn is insulated and can be heated up, thus storing the produced heat. The heat sink could be heated to temperatures above the rest of the ship's interior with heat pumps, but there is probably a sweet spot above which the heat pumps themselves create so much additional heat that it outweighs a higher heat sink capacity.

That reservoir, as well as any other possible part of the ship, should be cooled down as far as possible before a mission. If the vessel were unmanned it could be cooled down to 3K throughout (which probably means that it must be away from any warm planet, let alone star, when the mission starts).

So what we have is a flying thermos that looks like the cooling surfaces in your freezer ;-).

Comment: By the way, if someone played Mass Effect, the protagonist's ship had a "silent running" feature, where she was not dumping excess heat into the space, but was conserving it within the hull for a short period of time. And yes, being a good thermos, she was getting heated to inhumane temperatures on the inside while being as cool as the ambient space.

Answer (score 3):

Only temporarily (and only assuming the liquid nitrogen was cold as the background -- liquid helium temperatures are really the temperatures you're going for if you want to match thermal background radiation, and at that temperature nitrogen is a solid).

Let's say at t=0, you have a warm spacecraft with internal heat sources (people, fuel cells, equipment) and a cold jacket of ultracold material (liquid helium, solid nitrogen, whatever).  At that time, the jacket is emitting blackbody radiation that looks like the thermal background of the universe, and the ship is invisible.  At t=t1, sometime later, the jacket has absorbed some heat from the warm interior of the ship.  Now, one of two things happens.  Either the heat goes into changing the state of the jacket (say, boiling off some liquid helium), in which case the remaining jacket's temperature remains the same and the ship stays invisible (but for the venting gasses), or the jacket warms up (say, if you've just warmed the solid nitrogen coat, but haven't reached a phase transition), in which case the blackbody spectrum changes and the ship becomes more visible than before.  In the first case, you're fine until you run out of jacket to boil off; then your ship is visible.  In the second case, the jacket keeps warming until it has the equilibrium temperature of the interior of the ship.  If it hasn't undergone a phase transition (e.g. let's say it started as ultracold iron, and now it's just lukewarm iron), it now has a blackbody spectrum matching the naked ship, and either way your ship is visible.

The next thing that you'll probably say is, "Well, what if I *keep* the jacket cold?"  The question is, how will you do that?  If you have a magic heat sink for the heat that the jacket will absorb from the interior, just pump the interior heat directly into that sink -- no need for the jacket.  Unfortunately, any scheme for avoiding exterior radiation will presumably involve pumping heat into an interior reservoir, which will get hotter and hotter until the heat is no longer containable, and the ship will be (briefly) VERY visible.

So the short answer is, no: your interior heat has to go somewhere, and while you can delay its emission, you can't prevent it.  (Now, if the goal is to *temporarily* cloak a ship, that's doable, at the expense of having to dump more heat later.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It will mask its thermal signature and that could make you invisible to a thermal scanner but only if the spaceship and the surroundings are at the same temperature and this will not be the case in most scenarios in outer space, the temperature in outer space is −270 °C, nitrogen is to hot for it at around −160 °C and cause of the vacuum this would turn solid , helium on the other hand can be in a liquid state at −269 °C , this could work but you still have yo deal with the radiation energy coming from within the ship, maybe a super reflective surface in the inside that concentrates all that energy to a point were its stored until its emitted in a laser beam once it reaches maximun capacity (this gives room for a lot of tense story writing when the bad guys are looking for your ship and the heath storage system its about to mealt down), but some how this doesn't convince me... Another idea would be to have a sphere shaped shield or spaceship designed in such a way that its made with very small 'tiles' that are paired with another tile in the opposite side of the sphere, both receiving the spectrum of the other and emitting it in their respective side, dont know if the black body radiation of the materials to create that simulated spectrum would interfere with the signal emitted making this idea worthless.

Comment: Welcome Alex. Thank you for contributing. I am downvoting your answer, simply because your answe isn't well grounded in science. It seems most of your experience and intuition exists in Standard Temperature and Presure. You will find neither in space. The limit of the temperature that LN2 can get down to in a vacuum is really down to how low a pressure you can get, and Adiabatic Expansion.

Comment: @Aron I don't think that's true. LN2 will become solid below 60K or so at zero pressure -- indeed, at *any* pressure -- if I read the diagrams correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify the "sphere shaped shield" idea?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps water could be sprayed into a cloud, which will scatter and mask the heat in the direction you choose.

Some heat radiator system proposals suggest spraying water on the radiator as a way to dump heat quickly For combat operations, perhaps? When high heat systems must be cycled faster than the radiator can handle.

This same water supply could be applied to spray a cloud towards the ship or station one wishes to hide your heat from?

Answer (score 0):

Objects give off different wavelengths and amounts of radiation based on their temperature
which is called [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation).
The radiation is given off in a continuous spectrum in a curve with a peak at a certain frequency depending on the temperature.  There's a [cool interactive visualization](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/blackbody-spectrum) published by the University of Colorado that lets you play with parameters.  Unfortunately it only lets you go down to 200K, but fortunately they made the [source code](https://github.com/phetsims/blackbody-spectrum) available.  If you play around with their simulation:

- the sun is at 5850K, gives off 84 million watts per square meter with a peak of 500 nanometers which is in the visible range
- a body at 300K gives off only 459 watts per square meter with a peak at 9,659 nanometers which is in the infrared
- at 77K (modifying source required) it only gives off 2 watts per square meter with a peak at 37,633 nanometers which is also in the infrared, need to get to about 1,000,000 nanometers to push it into microwaves

So enemies could detect you, but you're giving off 1/200th the energy of something at 300K and 1/45th the energy of something at 200K (typical asteroid), so you would be that much harder to detect.  Also their equipment might need to be tuned for different frequencies or they may have to have different equipment all together to detect you compared to a normal ship.  If stealth ships are a new technology, they might not be prepared and miss you all together.

But you have to think about where the energy from your goes.  If you have a layer of vacuum between your actual hull and the liquid nitrogen, you'll cook inside if you're producing much energy at all.  If you dump heat into the liquid nitrogen it will boil and increase the pressure until your container bursts.  If you're near the sun and don't reflect it's radiation, that will warm it up too (ala 200K in the asteroid belt)  It might be efficient to have blocks of regular water ice for this purpose.  1kg of ice needs to absorb about 330kJ of energy to melt, then it will take another 420kJ to raise it to the boiling temperature.  So you can have a certain energy budget you can maintain your stealth mode for before you need to vent some of that heat.  If enemies are only in one direction, you could have heat pipes transferring that heat to a large radiator that could emit heat away from your enemies which would be nearly impossible to detect from the opposite direction.

You might be able to rendezvous with a comet or asteroid and dump some heat into that.
You would need some form of propulsion that would let you perform a rendezvous without being seen though, like some form of reactionless drive.  Even if you vent the liquid nitrogen for thrust, it will expand to make a larger cloud and will be warmed by the sun which will both serve to increase your energy signature and provide a way to track your trajectory.  If you start lighting off a fusion drive, you can forget about stealth.